getting issue in receiving the List<MyDtoClass> in Spring Boot Apache Camel REST API
github link: https://github.com/shahulsley/came-rest-dsl
I have written REST API in Spring Boot using Apache Camel REST DSL. All endpoints work fine except createBatch,
1. getById
2. getAllDocs
3. delete
4. deleteBatch
5. create
6. createBatch --- ISSUE (Not able receive the input as List. getting type conversion issue. tried many ways.
                   createBatch end point is "http://localhost:8080/my-rest-api/createBatch"

Input Body:
[
  {
    "shipperNumber": "AAAA",
    "startDate": "2024-08-05T11:40:15.123456",
    "endDate": "2024-09-01T02:36:15.678543"
  }, {
    "shipperNumber": "BBBB",
    "startDate": "2024-08-06T14:30:00.654321",
    "endDate": "2024-09-10T04:15:00.987654"
  }
]

Expectation: receive the List and retrieve one by one and call create single end point. Please let me know if you have any suggestion
Tried to convert it to List but it is getting failed

from("direct:createBatch")
.log("Received Message: " + "${body}")
.unmarshal(new JacksonDataFormat(RequestDTO.class))
.log("Unmarshalled Message: " + "${body}");                                                  This works well if the input JSON is a single object, not a list (array) of objects. Looks like, this is causing the issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Issue was receiving the Json as List. So, we need to tell the Camel, incoming data is List of DTO,
Below code resolved the issue.
restConfiguration()
    .component("servlet")
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off);  //Changed it to "off" from "json", manually unmarshal and marshal
    
JacksonDataFormat requestDataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat(RequestDTO.class);
requestDataFormat.useList();

from("direct:createBatch")
    .unmarshal(requestDataFormat)
    .bean(myRestService, "createShipperBatch(${body})")
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson);

